# PDFLaTeX: Straight quotes in URLs (no smartquotes in urls)

Tags: punctuation, urls, biber

Is it somehow possible to have straight quotes in URL's? Especially the single quote sign would be important to me, as this is the most confusing character within URL's, as the reader might not know which character on his keyboard that is.

It would be great if someone could point me out how to use straight quotes in URL's only (in my text I want to have the curly quotation marks).

My only idea would be the following: Use upquote package and set the url in a verbatim environment, but then `biber` throws out lots of error messages.

**It is important that the solution works for `\url` commands in the `.bib` file!**

Note: I don't want to set that stuff manually as part of the `\url` command, as the `\url` command automatically translates URL's to URI's for me, and therefore I don't have control over single characters being set!

EDIT:

Okay I am going to add an example:

```
@online{wiki3,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Prélude à l’après-midi d’un faune},
url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude_à_l'après-midi_d'un_faune},
note = "[Last accessed: May,12 2013]"
}
```

This is an example in my `.bib` file. 
It is printed like this:

[image]

**Note the `’` character instead of the correct one (`'`) in the URL.**

Now I want the single quotes to be straight, in the output pdf file they aren't.

Comment: It might be a lot more useful if you added some examples as to what you are refering to. Do you have quotes in the URLs, around it ....

Comment: Is it `biber` that makes the `%xx` conversion? In which case it ought to also reencode the single quotes, simply because thye can be wrong when copied from PDF.

Comment: What `\url` command in the .bib file? Are you not rather referring to the `url` *field*?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @GEO I took the liberty of modifying the question by adding an explanatory image. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: The correct URL is [`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l%27apr%C3%A8s-midi_d%27un_faune`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l%27apr%C3%A8s-midi_d%27un_faune).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Infact, it is badly translated by biber, as you can see in the image.

Comment: Karl, thank you very much for editing my Question. I don't see a reason for giving a minimal working example as the problem should be clear. 
Biber does not translate the characters, this is done by PDFLaTeX. Using other compilers that are aware of fontspec this problem can be solved very easy, but I want to stay with good old PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @karlkoeller `biber` fails to correct the given URL because this URL is not correct! The single quote can't be automatically encoded because it's a reserved character (see RFC. 3986).

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL is:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l%27apr%C3%A8s-midi_d%27un_faune
```

`biber` tries to correct the bad URLs. But it can't encode the single quote because it's a reserved character (see [RFC. 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12)).

Extract: *URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.*

**First Edit:** To find a correct URL, use your favorite web browser and copy the URL from its address bar. There is no automatic way to find a correct URL.

**Second Edit:** With the following document, the first URLs is *displayed* with smart quotes but the actual link uses original straight quotes (open the PDF with your editor to verify the actual link). With some PDF viewers, this first link does **not** work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l%27apr%C3%A8s-midi_d%27un_faune}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay two questions:
1.) How two find out the correct URL in an automated way?
2.) Is there no LaTeX way of solving this problem? Is it not possible to write a function that replaces that character in URLs?
Apart from that: Even if the generated URL is not entirely correct, it works. The issue would not be getting rid of the single quote, but forcing the use of a straight quote instead.

Comment: @GEO: 1.) Pages of Wikipedia have a left sidebar with `Cite this page` below `Toolbox`. This shows a "permanent link" with a correctly quoted URL. 2.) It could be done in (La)TeX, if the encoding would be known. There is a recommendation for UTF-8, but it is only a recommendation. Also domain names are encoded differently ([Punycode](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)). Thus a parser for URIs is needed as well.